# Why an email address must not exceed 254 characters?

Tags: email, domain-name, email-address

I have a question about the email addresses length.
Why in wikipedia or in some other sites tell that the maximum number of chars in an email-user-name is 64, that the server-name must have maximum 255 chars and that together the user-name-mail@server-name must not exceed 254 characters?

If it must have 254 chars, why the server-name must not exceed 255??? I don't understand that...

Could you help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant SMTP standard is currently [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321). Section 4.5.3 describes the limits. The length of a mail path can't exceed 256 bytes.  Since a mail path includes angle brackets, practically this means the user@host portion can't exceed 254 characters.

Comment: Thank you for the response. So an address like this is ok?:
`1@252`

Where the numbers are the number of chars.

Comment: Yes. Your domain name services provider or your domain registrar may choose to limit the length of a domain name to be shorter that, of course.

Comment: Thank you! And is there a minumum amount of chars? For example 6:
**1@1.2**

Comment: Yes, 1@1.2 is the shortest currently possible address for Internet mail according to the standard, which requires fully-qualified domain names.  Some mailers will accept non-fully-qualified domain names, where you don't have a dot and a top-level domain, so it is possible to set up your own private network where 1@1 addresses will work.